# Exception while configuring hibernate with HSQLDB

Tags: hibernate, exception, hsqldb, derby

I created a database connection called New HSQLDB.  I was able to successfully connect and ping the DB from eclipse.

I created hibernate congif file with the below data :

```
<property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">org.hsqldb.jdbcDriver</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:hsqldb:localhost</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.username">sa</property>
    <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.HSQLDialect</property>
```

And when i try to create a console, it is throwing error. It is unable to make a connection. The data provided in the config file is generated from the database configuration details. I tried the same with Derby. It threw me error at the same point.

Is there something wrong with my url.

When i searched online, most of them had the format ://localhost:. How do get this ? Since i was able to ping the DB, doesnt that mean my url and config file data is correct ?

Thank you.

Comment: So did you start a HSQLDB **server** before running your application?

Comment: <property name="hibernate.connection.url" value="jdbc:hsqldb:hsql://localhost/YOURDBNAME"/>

Comment: I connected the database and pinged it. Is there something else I should do ?

Comment: where does the connection url actually point to ?

Comment: Thank you. It worked. I hadnt started the server. I ran the runServer.bat file and then it worked